# AWS Google Sign In - Query Dynamo DB Access Denied Error

Tags: ios, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-ios

I am having a iOS application that uses Google SignIn and I want to authenticate AWS using Google Token ID.

I have created roles in IAM and Identity Pool in Cognito.When I try to query a table in Dynamo. I am getting

```
'Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity'
```

I have the trusted policy having my google client ID,

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
      "Federated": "accounts.google.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity",
      "Condition": {
      "StringEquals": {
      "accounts.google.com:aud": #mygoogleclientid#
    }
  }
}
]}
```

Error

```
  Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSSTSErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo=
  {
     Type=Sender, 
     Message=Not authorized to perform sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity,
     Code=AccessDenied, __text=(
     "\n    ",
     "\n    ",
     "\n    ",
     "\n  "
  )}
```

I want to understand why I get this error and a solution to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend that you try the Enhanced Authflow, so that Cognito will make the sts:AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity call for you.

Reference to auth flow documentation here:
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/identity/concepts/authentication-flow/

Here is Cognito's Basic Auth flow:
GetId -> GetOpenIdToken (Cognito's Open Id token) -> AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity (passing Cognito's Open Id token).

If you create your identity pool in the AWS console, the default policies are setup to work with the either the Enhanced Flow or the Basic Flow. You'd just have to add a policy for DynamoDB access and for other services you'd like to integrate with.